# Error of thread sigabrt in iOS and it crashes my app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

When I run my app it always shows that a thread error of signal `sigabrt` has been occurred in class `appDelegate`

> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: can you show your exception report

Comment: Does the app run in the simulator?

Comment: nope it can't be run on simulator.

Comment: 2015-07-13 11:34:25.224 Cards[703:27092] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'

Comment: Hello @shahinaliagharia put your appdelegate code.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learnt: When deleting any outlets for vars in the implementation, make sure to unhook the respective connection in the IB

It means the signal between the simulator and your code has been abrupted. Check all your code connections with you UI elements.

Ctrl-/right-click on the File's Owner in the Xcode editor, look for a warning triangle. Clear that out (by deleting the connection or re-connecting it to the proper outlet) and you'll likely be good.

[image]